# Wrong URL for Django filefields download link

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, django-uploads

I'm currently doing a web app that would store files. I have my class lobby like this :

```
class Lobby(models.Model):

    (...)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text="Unique ID for this particular lobby across whole database")
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='./documents/',blank=True, null=True)

    (...)

    def file_link(self):
        if self.pdf:
            return "<a href='%s' download>Download</a>" % (self.pdf.url)
        else:
            return "No attachment"

    file_link.allow_tags = True
    file_link.short_description = 'file_link'
    (...)
```

When I'm instanciating a lobby I can easily upload my pdf and it goes to the right place (at the root of my app in file named 'documents').

But here's the problem, when I'm trying to download the file thanks to a link by calling:

```
  <p><strong>File:</strong> {{ lobby.file_link|safe}}</p>
```

I'm not getting document, but a file not found error

```
Firefox doesn't find the file  http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/lobby/73d5aede-96af-445e-bec9-8c4522d37ce7/documents/the document.pdf
```

It's like the file_link doesn't send the place the file is stored, but the name the url to go to the page a a specific lobby, then the URL.

What did I do wrong??

Thanks.

Edit : worked by adding the enctype='multipart/form-data' attribute of form in HTML.

Comment: did you try to remove the `|safe`?

Comment: Hi, in fact I solved the problem it didn't exactly came from here. I fact in my html form I forgot the ***enctype='multipart/form-data'*** attribute of form. Hence the request.FILE was everytime empy.